# loading html into MVC page with jQuery (?)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here's the thing.

I have a page in MVC. this page has a **helper.**

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("foldingHelpBox", ViewData["foldingHelpBox"]); %>
```

So **the Action:**

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? verbID, string schooljaarparam) {
        ......

        ViewData["foldingHelpBox"] = new InfoFlyout() { Title = "How does this work?", Message =  "foldinghelpbox.html" }; 

        return View();
    }
```

**What is an InfoFlyout?**

```
public partial class InfoFlyout {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

**What do I want?**

I want an Accordeon like effect, a title and a message. the message is defaultly closed, and opens when you click the title. but I want just 1 item, not multiple like the accordeon has.

**The jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".foldingHelpText").hide();
    $(".foldingHelp").click(function () {
        var helptext = $(this).siblings(".foldingHelpText");
        if (helptext.is(":hidden")) {
            alert(helptext.attr("data"));
            helptext.load(helptext.attr("data"));
        }
        $(this).siblings(".foldingHelpText").toggle("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
        return false;
    });

    $(".closedialog").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
    });
});
```

**The Partial**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MVC2_NASTEST.Models.InfoFlyout>" %>
<div class="foldingHelpBox">
    <a class="foldingHelp" href="#">
        <%= Model.Title %></a>
    <div class="foldingHelpText" data="<%= Model.Message %>">
        <span class="closedialog ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" title="Sluiten">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
```

**So tell me the problem!**

Well, The `Message` can be 2 things. It can be a string which contains the message, or it could be a string with is actually the name of the HTML file which contains the actual html to put inside the message. This html can be fairly long, that's why i do not want to write it all in 1 string.

The problem is that I am using MVC and the HTML file is in my View folder. I can move it somewhere else though.

I'd like to have DRY code.

there are 2 questions:

**How would you do it?** 
I am now trying to use the `jQuery load` function to read the html into the `foldinghelptext` div but i cant get the URL right to the html file. So how would you do it? maybe put the HTML in a partial, name it. the whole lot doesn't look so clean to me.

**How do i get the URL of this html file**

If my way of doing it is fine, how do i get the URL to the html file, to let jQuery load it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok Why i love stackoverflow: when i finish to write my question I get a great idea which usually fixes the problem :D

What did i do?

i placed the html from the HTML file in a `partial`

then, in the **Action**

```
        ViewData["foldingHelpBox"] = new InfoFlyout() { Title = "Hoe werkt dit?", Message = "partialname" };
```

**the main partial:**

```
<div class="foldingHelpBox">
    <a class="foldingHelp" href="#">
        <%= Model.Title %></a>
    <div class="foldingHelpText">
        <span class="closedialog ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" title="Sluiten">&nbsp;</span>
        <% Html.RenderPartial(Model.Message); %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**the jQuery** for the sliding open and close

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".foldingHelpText").hide();
    $(".foldingHelp").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings(".foldingHelpText").toggle("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
        return false;
    });

    $(".closedialog").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
    });
});
```

so now I only have, as jfar suggested, html input which is very DRY

Answer (score 1):

**How do i get the URL of this html file**

To get the qualified path to the html file try to use [Url.Content()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx)

> Converts a virtual (relative) path to
>   an application absolute path.

```
<div class="foldingHelpText" data="<%=Url.Content("~/SomePathToHtmlFile/" +  Model.Message )%>">
  <span class="closedialog ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" title="Sluiten">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The DRYest thing to do would be to always load the message from either html or a string and not support both.

I'd go for html in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Action in a Controller and have the method return like

```
return base.File("~/WhateverPath/htmlPage.htm", "text/html");
```

Then yon can have any URL you want.